How to hide an optgroup element when it does not contain any option element that is not disabled using CSS
I want to hide an optgroup element when it doesn't have any option element which cannot be selected. In the example below the first optgroup element shall be shown and the second should be hidden.


optgroup {
    display: none;
}
optgroup:has(option:not(:disabled)) {
    display: unset;
}
<select id="location" name="location">
    <option value="" selected="">Standort wählen</option>
    <optgroup label="Kanton Luzern">
        <option value="buttisholz">Buttisholz</option>
        <option value="littau" disabled="">Littau</option>
        <option value="luzern">Luzern</option>
        <option value="malters" disabled="">Malters</option>
        <option value="schuepfheim">Schüpfheim</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Kanton Schaffhausen">
        <option value="schaffhausen" disabled="">Schaffhausen</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>



I have come up with this solution which seems to work (only tested in Chrome) but I am looking for a solution with just one statement instead of 2 if that is possible:
optgroup {
  display: none;
  }
optgroup:has(option:not(:disabled)) {
  display: unset;
  }

I tried this version which doesn't work because it seems that the :enabled pseudo selector can only be used for input, select and textarea fields:
optgroup:not(option:enabled) {
  display: none;
  }


@Paulie_D Thank you for your feedback. I didn't know the points. I edited my post and added the code in a Stack Snippet.

Keep it simple and readable!
use css :enabled


optgroup:not(:has(option:enabled)) {
  display: none;
}
<select id="location" name="location">
  <option value="" selected   disabled > Standort wählen </option>
  <optgroup label="Kanton Luzern">
      <option value="buttisholz"       > Buttisholz </option>
      <option value="littau"  disabled > Littau     </option>
      <option value="luzern"           > Luzern     </option>
      <option value="malters" disabled > Malters    </option>
      <option value="schuepfheim"      > Schüpfheim </option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Kanton Schaffhausen">
      <option value="schaffhausen" disabled > Schaffhausen </option>
  </optgroup>
</select>




Strange that the :enabled selector initially didn't work for me but here is written that it can be used on option elements and it works: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics-other.html#selector-enabled

In Safari browser it is not working and it seems that there is not workaround with CSS.

@flip witch one and witch version ? ? :not()  or :has()  or :enabled  see also -> https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Aenabled

@flip At Apple, the evolution of Safari to respect all HTML5 / CSS3 / JavaScript features always arrives very late, and Mac OS updates are known to reject systems that are more than 3 generations old. Many Apple customers end up preferring to use another browser, like Firefox or Chromium

I have't investigated the issue in detail because as you write Safari has a low market share. The issue seems to be not related to the selectors but rather that Apple / Safari does not allow to hide option elements (display:none;) due to their point of view on UX. You would need to remove the whole -tags from the HTML code.

Here's a single-statement solution that should work across modern browsers and provide the desired behavior of hiding optgroup elements that do not have any non-disabled option elements.
optgroup:not(:has(option:not(:disabled))) {
  display: none;
}

Here's how it works:

The optgroup:not(:has(option:not(:disabled))) selector selects all
optgroup elements that do not have a child option element that is not
disabled.

The :has() pseudo-class is used to check if the optgroup element has
a child option element that is not disabled.

The :not() pseudo-class is then used to negate this condition,
effectively targeting the optgroup elements that do not have any
non-disabled option elements as children.

The display: none; rule is then applied to the targeted optgroup
elements, hiding them.



Thanks a lot incl. your detailed answer. That's exactly what I needed and I was so close ;-).
